# Ring Oscillator Device Driver

Tags: linux, driver, device, dts

I have been asked to bring up a Ring Oscillator in Linux. To start with I have tried reading the control and status registers  (interesting bits) directly and I can access those with devmem  (using physical addresses of the registers). There are two Ring Oscillator modules 0 and 1. Each consistes of 4 Ring Oscillators. Module 0 output feeds a Random Number Generator. Module 1 is used for Process Monitoring - not much information yet on this. Each module has seperate set of registers for control, status etc. There is a Frequency Counter attached to each Ring Oscillators and I can read frequency count from the count register of the Frequency Counter when appropriately set the control registers of the Ring Oscillators.

Now I have to write a  device driver for the Ring Oscillator for the bring up purpose. What I am not quite clear is whether in the dts file I should try representing the Ring Oscillator as a clock source or to treat it as a platform device. Couldn't figure out much information on how Linux handles a Ring Oscillator.  Should I be looking for the device address of the Ring Oscillator and try adding it as any other platform peripheral device entry in the dts file. In that can I can register it as a platform device in the driver file and control its registers from the probe function. Or should I treat it as a clock source? However, from the available documentation I cannot see it is being used as a clock source for any other peripherals. Can anyone throw some light on this please? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Regards

Vivek

Answer (score 0):

I have implmented the Ring Oscillator as a platform driver. The dts/dtsi changes are as below:

dtsi:

```
ring_osc: ring-oscillator@F00xxxxx {
    compatible = "abc,abc-ring";
    reg = <0xF00xxxxx 0x14>;
    status = "disabled";
};
```

dts:

```
&ring_osc {
    status = "okay";
};
```

The driver I have written simply configures the oscillator using it's configuration registers. Also, provides a sysfs interface for setting the period values for the frequency counter which is attached to it and read back the frequency count from the frequency counter.